# ASp.Net repeater control : error showing on binding repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net

It shows error "Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem.DataItem' cannot be used like a method.

for the  <%# Container.DataItem("CostPageDescription")%>

my code below,

```
                 <td> Cost Page Description</td>
                 <td> Vendor Name</td>
                 <td> Bill Type</td>
             </tr>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
               <td> <%# Container.DataItem("CostPageDescription")%></td>
               <td> <%# Container.DataItem("VendorName")%> </td>
               <td> <%# Container.DataItem("BillType") %> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
```

Comment: I removed <`td> <%# Container.DataItem("CostPageDescription")%></td>` , but same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USE LIKE THIS

```
<td> <%# eval("CostPageDescription")%></td>
```

and at one place u left it blank, so make that correct

Comment: Getting error `The name 'eval' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Use `Eval()` (type sensitive)

Comment: DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CostPageDescription")

Comment: @user2543573 if above does not work, then there must be some other problem, becuase the above syntax is full one

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<%# Eval("CostPageDescription") %>
```

or this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CostPageDescription") %>
```

First one is just a simplification of the second.